# Flexible layout with fixed-width and available space in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a specific layout in React Native for iOS. I'll explain the layout, and I have added an image and links to demonstrate it.

**Left**

The left area (in red) should contain 2 items; a Title and a Tag. Both items should appear on the same line.

- Title: The Title can vary in length. It should use all available space, and have an ellipsis if too long.
- Tag: The Tag can vary in length, it should always be shown in full, and be placed immediately after the Title.

**Right**

The right area (in yellow) has a fixed width.

I have created the layout successfully using CSS at CodePen here: https://codepen.io/madebyew/pen/VwwPaWZ

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 600px;
}
.left {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}
.right {
  width: 20%;
}
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tag {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: CSS]

I have tried to recreate the same layout using React Native, but without success, here: https://snack.expo.io/@madebyew/flex-alignment

[image]

The issue I am facing is that in React Native, the Title only truncates to fit itself in its parent, instead of truncating to allow its Tag single to share its parent's space.

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired layout? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some flex look at this:

https://snack.expo.io/Bk8GFDjKH

Comment: Unfortunately your changes align the Tag to the right of the lefthand (red) area. I need the Tag to appear immediately after the end of the Title, as shown in the first screenshot.

Comment: You should read the docs about flexGrow, flexShrink and flexBasis. I think the solution is there

Comment: I have been reading the docs already, but I do appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately I have not yet found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    render() {
    return (
        <View style = {{width: '100%', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
            <View style = {{width: '100%', height: 50, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <View style = {{flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                        <Text numberOfLines = {1}>ssdflk dfjljsd  sdfj sdfkjs df jlskdf </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {{flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                        <Text>Tags</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style = {{width: 80, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'yellow', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                    <Text>Right</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I tried this code, looks working for your idea

Comment: Unfortunately this positions the Tag to the right of the lefthand area. I created a demo of your suggestion at https://snack.expo.io/@madebyew/flex-alignment-v2-so. See the second row which has a short Title, the Tag should appear directly after that text (so the title needs to reduce to fit its text). Thanks for the suggestion.